# How to sum BigDecimal properties of objects in Java8 lambda expression?

Tags: java, java-8

Let's get a simple real life example:

```
BigDecimal invoiceValue = BigDecimal.ZERO;
for (InvoiceItem i : invoiceItems) {
    invoiceValue = invoiceValue.add(i.getItemValue());
}
```

How to get this in one statement with Java8 lambda expression?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
invoiceItems.stream()
    .map(Item::getItemValue)
    .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)
```

Comment: That was fast as a bullet! What an odd name to this method though. Thanks!

Comment: I think that the BigDecimal.ZERO is an optional parameter in this case, since without it it will just apply "add" to the first two elements of the stream to kick things off.

Comment: @JasonReid: No, in that case it will return an `Optional<BigDecimal>`, which is not really what is wanted.

Comment: Ah right, thanks! I missed that subtlety in what it was replacing.

Comment: You can still use `.reduce(BigDecimal::add).orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO)` but it wouldn’t be exactly the same as the code in the question anymore…

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the reduce method that takes a BiFunction as parameter:

```
BigDecimal invoiceValue = invoiceItems.stream().reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, (bd, item) -> bd.add(item.getItemValue()), BigDecimal::add);
```

Comment: Why does one have to define the add method in the combiner? You already defined the add-functionality in your accumulator.